# Get All Div's of Active Page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a couple of pages,i want to get all div having class `live`.I try following code:

```
function SendAjaxCall(data,activeHub)
{
    if (data!=-1) {
        $('.live').each(function (i, obj) {
            FetchLiveTiles("google.com");
        });
    }
}
```

i want to call  FetchLiveTiles(""),for only `activeHub` page.i-e i want to run `each` function for all that div's that have `live` class and are in current `activeHub` page.How can i do that?

Comment: The question doesn't really make much sense, what isn't working and what exactly are you trying to do. What is `activeHub` and how are you getting it etc.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `page`?

Comment: active hub is my current page and i want to get all div's of this current page having class live

Comment: @MuhammadAli The javascript by default has full scope for and only the current page.

Comment: @MuhammadAli May be Hendra's answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: Should be easy, just do `$('.live', activeHub).each(function (i, obj) { ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$(activeHub).find('div.live').each(function(){
    //your code goes here.
    //$(this) in this context will give you the required div within activeHub context    
});
```

EDIT:

Also, if you intend to find all the `div`s with `.live` you can put this code on `each page` where you want to perform this task,

```
$('div.live').each(function(){
    //your code goes here.
});
```

Comment: i want stuff like this before your editing,but it not working,it not come in If condition.

Comment: It means, there is some problem with your `data` parameter.

Comment: All the required data is correct,i think $(selector),it is the thing the code can't find

Comment: This is a bit confusing, can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($('.live'), function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

Comment: it's behavior is same as my code give above.I want to get all div's having class `live` and are under `activeHub` page

Comment: if activehub is your current page then you should have no problem to get all divs which have .live class. by default JavaScript has full scope to current page (in your case activehub).

Answer (score 0):

The javascript by default has full scope for and only the current page.
To search only the `div`s, change the selector like this:

```
$('div.live').each(function () {
    FetchLiveTiles("google.com");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var path = window.location.href; // get url
    var loc = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/')+1); // get page

  if(loc == 'activeHub')
  {
    $('.live').each(function (i, obj)
      {      
           FetchLiveTiles("google.com");

       });
  }
```

first u get url, and substring the url to get page requested, and in document ready u can perform checking.

note : as others said, javascript by default can access all ur current page components, so below code actually will work too, but for ur question, may be above code is what u are looking for.

```
$('.live').each(function ()
          {      
               FetchLiveTiles("google.com");

           });
```

Comment: However, you can't fetch the content of the page this way. To do so, you'll have to get the contents using XmlHttp request object :)

Comment: @Maverick The OP intends to run this code only when the page `activeHub` is loaded. No need to fetch the content of that page.

Comment: yes just like @P5Coder said, and it's just a sample anyway :)

Comment: Then why does he need to pass `activeHub` as an argument? All the elements in current page are accessible by default.

Comment: @Maverick The OP is not passing `activehub` as argnument. He/she is checking if the current page's name is `activehub`. P.S.: I presume it's 'she' rather than `he'. :)

Comment: I'd suggest not to play with window.location. Instead, it'd be better to refactor the code and put it in the pages only where you have to execute the functionality.